# Can my application know its Git Tag?

Tags: git, tags

I seem to remember seeing in one other revision management system that you could put a complicated magic string in your code and the revision management system would automatically replace that pattern by a version string.
The point is that I would like an about dialog box in my application which displays the current version. In everything I have seen about Git, it does not change a single bit of your sources. Another idea is that git creates a single text file that the sources can read to 
display the version. 
I don't like the idea of having to call Git and copying the tag by hand into my code.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup a post-commit hook calling a python script like [**`manuelbua/gitver`**](https://github.com/manuelbua/gitver)
(from [Manuel Bua](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50770/manuel), also [on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50770/manuel)).

Goal:

> I want the version string and/or other useful information to be embedded in the application code automatically, "compiled-in" so to speak, without me having to remember to do it manually each time.

Workflow:

> - you are working on your repository, now you are ready to promote the current version to the next release
> - create a release tag, `git tag -a v0.0.2 -m 'Bump version'`
> - defines your `NEXT` version, the one you are going to work towards to by running `gitver next 0.0.3`
> - run `gitver` and check everything is fine
> - OPTIONAL: preview or update your project's version information templates by running `gitver preview <template name>` or `gitver update <template name>`, then rebuild the project to reflect version changes
> - any other manual house-keeping in-between releases can be performed now
> - now you are working towards the NEXT release, repeat when release time has came again

That helps you generate a file with the right metadata information (like the version derived from the app last tag), for you to use during the build.

Comment: @Manuel No problem, and thank you for that script. I have edited the answer for make the proper attribution more visible.

Answer (score 1):

1. Git doesn't support expandable "Keywords" - it's Linus's policy

> In everything I have seen about Git, it does not change a single bit of your sources

Wrong. It can and it do it - "text normalization" for cross-platform usage is big git's headache

> The point is that I would like an about dialog box in my application which displays the current version.

Under the hood it's almost always `git describe` output, which command (on *build stage*) you can use on your working dir, store and use later

- Pro: simplicity
- Contra: add additional level of complexity in build-process

Another implementation is "smudge|clean filters": keyword, stored as static text in repository, converted to dynamically changing element in working directory (really - related to filters programs perform this bidirectional transformation)

- Pro: transparency (you have all already inside sources in repository)
- Contra: Lesser portability (filter's action must be available on each workplace), possible complexity of transformation rules

Answer (score 0):

I simply ask the OS/Git for the tag info. This is my version view (php):

```
<?php
$output = [];
exec("git tag", $output);
$version = end($output);
?>
{{$version}}
```

That way i only store the version in one place.